# How to data bind a list of objects with a list property?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an object Classroom with a list Student, as shown below.

```
public class Classroom
{
    public int Number
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Student> StudentList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

My Student object look like this.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I am using Xamarin Forms to develop a cross platform app that shows a ListView of all the classroom numbers, as a header for the cell, and underneath a list of the students name.

This is my C# for the ListView.ItemSource

```
List<Classroom> ClassroomList = new List<Classroom>();

ClassroomList.add(new Classroom());
ClassroomList.add(new Classroom());
ClassroomList.add(new Classroom());

MyListView.ItemSource = ClassroomList;
```

My problem is that each Classroom object has a different amount of students in the list. I don't know how to use data binding in XAML or C# to list all the classroom numbers with a "sub list" of all the students.

[Here is an example of what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChbgJ.png)

If anyone can help me use my data model to bind the data in my ListView. It would help a lot.

I've been looking all over the place to find the answer and [this is the closest answer is I found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782216/bind-a-list-property-of-an-object-to-a-listview)

Comment: you want to display a List of students, not classrooms. Use LINQ to create a list of Students that is grouped by Classroom, then bind that to a Grouped ListView

Comment: I looked into Grouped ListView is there a way to make it collapse and expand like my picture?